# How to remove a substring after a substring?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, string

I have the following string:

```
somestring = "Zero function argument 1 since code 345 and from code 8476 then it goes on"
```

I want to remove `since code 345` and `from code 8476` (those numbers can vary) but I want to keep the `1` in `argument 1` in the string.

I am doing the following:

```
import re

somestring = "Zero function argument 1 since code 345 and from code 8476 then it goes on"
somestring = somestring.replace("since code", "").replace("from code", "")
stringlist = somestring.split(" ")
pattern = '[0-9]'
print([re.sub(pattern, "", i) for i in stringlist])
```

But the output removes the `1` from `argument 1` in the string. The output looks like this:
`['Zero', 'function', 'argument', '', '', '', 'and', '', '', 'then', 'it', 'goes', 'on']`

But the ideal output I want is `Zero function argument 1 and then it goes on` i.e. remove any number after `since code` and `from code`, remove "since code" and "from code", and do not have `''` in the string or the list.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a regex replacement here:

```py
somestring = "Zero function argument 1 since code 345 and from code 8476 then it goes on"
output = re.sub(r'\s*\b(?:since|from) code \d+\s*', ' ', somestring).strip()
print(output)  # Zero function argument 1 and then it goes on
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're after:

```
import re

somestring = "Zero function argument 1 since code 345 and from code 8476 then it goes on"
result = re.sub(r'(?:since|from) code \d+ ', '', somestring)
print(result)
```

Note that there's a space after `\d+`, since the string you're replacing would have have space before it and one after it, in your example. If the phrase `since code 123` could also appear in quotes, or before a comma or period for example, then you might want something like this:

```
import re

somestring = "Zero function argument 1 since code 345, and from code 8476 as well. Then it goes on"
result = re.sub(r'\s*(?:since|from) code \d+\s*', ' ', somestring)
print(result)
```

(which is very similar to what @TimBiegeleisen posted)